# CruiseControl.Net allowForceBuild per project?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

From reading the docs I can tell that allowForceBuild will turn off the force build button for the server.

In my case I have 12 projects.
Once is a weekend cleanup task.

I want to remove the force build on this one project.   Is there a way to turn off the button on a project level?

Thanks.

-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [Project Level Security](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Level+Security)

Add this to your configuration:

```
<project>
  <!-- [...] -->
  <security type="defaultProjectSecurity">
    <permissions>
      <userPermission name="*" forceBuild="Deny" />
    </permissions>
  </security>
  <!-- [...] -->
</project>
```

If You haven't modified the configuration on the server level, `forceBuild` should be set to `Allow` by default and will be overridden in Your project then.

Comment: Are there any examples out there fo how to do this?
Thanks!
C-

Comment: Though I have no practical experience with CI security introduced in CCNET 1.5, I added a configuration snippet to my answer. Absolutely no guarantee, just how I understand the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly same reply as **The Chairman**.
In your project config, add the security line :

```
<project name="xxx">
  <!-- Source control block defined here -->
  <!-- Tasks defined here -->
  <!-- Publishers defined here -->
  <security type="defaultProjectSecurity" forceBuild="Deny">
  </security>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.6+, you can hide the "Force" and "Stop" buttons in your ccnet.config:

```
<project name="xxx">
  <!-- Source Control -->
  <!-- Tasks -->
  <!-- Publishers -->
  <showForceBuildButton>False</showForceBuildButton>
  <showStartStopButton>False</showStartStopButton>
</project>
```

Reference: [Project Configuration Block](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Project_Configuration_Block)